# Filtrations of the irreducible representations of the symmetric groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

For a partition $\lambda$ of $n$, write $S^{\lambda}$ for the irreducible $S_n$-representation that corresponds to $\lambda$ (a.k.a. the Specht module).
For two integers $d<n$ write $Par_d(n) = \{\lambda\vdash n | r(\lambda)\leq d\}$ for the set of all partitions of $n$ with at most $d$ rows.

**Question 1** For $d_1,d_2\leq n$, is it true that
$$\{\lambda\vdash n| \text{Hom}_{S_n}(S^{\lambda},S^{\lambda_1}\otimes S^{\lambda_2})\neq 0 \text{ for some } \lambda_1\in Par_{d_1}(n), \lambda_2\in Par_{d_2}(n)\} = Par_{d_1d_2}(n)?$$ The tensor product here has the diagonal $S_n$-action.

**Question 2**: For integers $d_1,d_2,n$, is it true that

$$\{\lambda\vdash n| \text{Hom}_{S_{n}}(S^{\lambda},\text{Ind}_{S_{n_1}\times S_{n_2}}^{S_{n}}(S^{\lambda_1}\otimes S^{\lambda_2})\neq 0 \text{ for some }n_1, n_2=n-n_1,\lambda_1\in Par_{d_1}(n_1), \lambda_2\in Par_{d_2}(n_2)\} = Par_{d_1+d_2}(n)?$$

Assume now that $G$ is a finite group that acts faithfully transitively on a set with $m$ elements. We then have an embedding $i:S_n\ltimes G^n\to S_{nm}$. The irreducible representations of $S_n\ltimes G^n$ can be described using the irreducible representations of $G$ and of $S_n$ (this appears, for example, in the work of Zelevinsky).

**Question 3** What are all the irreducible constituents of $$\bigoplus_{\lambda\in Par_d(nm)}\text{Res}^{S_{nm}}_{S_n\ltimes G^n}(S^{\lambda})$$